# LGBM's best_iteration_ is None when using early early_stopping callback even though early stopping occurs

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

If I fit a model with

```
gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=250)
gbm.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
    eval_metric='l2',
    callbacks=[lgb.early_stopping(3)],
    verbose=-1
)
```

the output is

```
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[210]   valid_0's l2: 0.00261499
```

But `gbm.best_iteration_` is None. I think it should be 210?

If I run the same model but use `early_stopping_rounds=3` instead of `callbacks=...`, I do get `gbm.best_iteration_` of 210. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that's the [documented](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.best_iteration_) behavior:

**lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.best_iteration_**:
The best iteration of fitted model if early_stopping() callback has been specified.